# Making "durable" objects

Tags: python, store

I'm programming a complex tree structure in Python and I'm tired of creating tree objects and filling them with data everytime I run the code.

So, is there a way to make your objects "durable" in Python. With "durable" I mean if there is a way to save all my objects as bytes in a file, so when I run the code again, I can create and fill all my objects with the data in the byte-file, restoring the state I left the last time I ran the code.

I guess there may be a post with this same question, but I can't think of a better term for "durable" in english.

Comment: "Persistent" is the word you're looking for. Check out the `shelve` and `pickle` modules.

Comment: @Gabe that was the magic word I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pickle` module to `serialize` your data (which is the general phrase for turning your in-memory representation into something that can be written to disk).  You read more in [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

The simplest code looks like this to store your object in a file:

```
pickle.dump(myobject, open('myfile', 'w'))
```

And to read it back in:

```
myobject = pickle.load(open('myfile', 'r'))
```

Comment: what's the usual filename suffix for this kind of files? `.dat`?

Comment: I don't think there's really a standard, although I have seen `.pck` used here and there.

Comment: I normally see these with `.pkl` (and that is what I use).

Answer (score 1):

For simple persistence, I recommend the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module.